# How to resolve this Error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i try this code and It is giving me the error on the 'where'
i verify: `using system.linq;` and `using System.Data.Entity` but not fixed(i work with visual studio 2012 ultimate and sql server 2008 r2)

code:

```
public static int updatecondidate(int condidateID, condidate_table   updatedcondidateData)
{ int rowAffected = 0;

    using (EmployeementSystemEntities DB = new EmployeementSystemEntities())
    {
        //select condidate for update
        condidate_table condidateforupdate = (from anything in DB.condidate_table
                                              where anything.condidate_id == condidateID
                                              select anything).FirstOrDefault();
        condidateforupdate.condidate_name = updatedcondidateData.condidate_name;
        condidateforupdate.condidate_phone = updatedcondidateData.condidate_phone;
        condidateforupdate.condidate_email = updatedcondidateData.condidate_email;
        condidateforupdate.condidate_pic = updatedcondidateData.condidate_pic;
        rowAffected = DB.SaveChanges();
    }
    return rowAffected;
}
```

the same error here on "Select"
 //select all condidate

```
public static List<condidate_table> SelectAllCondidate()
{
    using (EmployeementSystemEntities DB = new EmployeementSystemEntities())
    {
        List<condidate_table> AllCondidate = (from anything in DB.condidate_table 
                                              select anything).ToList<condidate_table>();
        return AllCondidate;
    }
}
```

Comment: This last query also doesn't work?

Comment: Can you try condidate_table condidateforupdate = DB.condidate_table.Where(c => c.condidate_id == condidateID).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: the same error with message:"impossible de convertir expression lambda en type 'string' car il ne s'agit pas  d'un type délégué"

Comment: @mehdiboudhir Can you list all of the using statements that you are using in the question?  Maybe that will help us identify one that might be missing.

Comment: @mehdiboudhir Do you get the same error if you using the method syntax rather than the query syntax?

Comment: Can you add the code for your condidate_table?

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<ISSUES> ListIssues()
{
    List<ISSUES> list = new List<ISSUES>();
    using (FTUEntities1 db = new FTUEntities1())
    {
        list = db.ISSUES.Include(a => a.CLIENTS).ToList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

In my case I missed this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score -1):

`where anything.condidate_id = condidateID` should be `where anything.condidate_id == condidateID` (note the double equals).

Here is a general list of issues, that I can find, that people are reporting has caused this same error for them.  I will update it as I find more.

**Query Syntax**

- using `=` instead of `==` in the where clause
- referencing variables in the query statement that have not been declared
- using incorrect punctuation for variable names (goes to the second point)
- calling a method inside the query and forgetting the parentheses, e.g. `c.FullNameReverse` instead of `c.FullNameReverse()`
- missing conditional operators (`&&`, `||`, etc...) in the where clause when creating compound predicates
- referencing static properties as if they were instance properties
- referencing object properties that do not exist

**Missing using statements**

- `using System.Linq`
- `using System.Data.Entity`

Comment: this problem not resolved yet .i try they previous helps but no changes.the same message appear

Comment: @JasonBoyd Ah, I made my comment when there was just a one-line answer; I now see you have expanded to a full answer, so I have deleted my comment.

Comment: I am not sure what else we can do to help based on the information provided.  @Fjodr and I have asked for additional information in the comments to the original question.